# Alternative to Cross Site Cookies for embedded widget login in React

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a react widget that loads on many websites from a my server. It allows users to login and interact with their account using cookies.

This works great, except when users disable 3rd party cookies, which is now the default in some browsers, for example Safari.

What secure methods are there to allow users to sign in to their accounts in the widget and remain signed in when navigating within the host site?